# Set element height to 100 % on a rowspan td?

Tags: html, css

Given this table:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2"><a>Hello</a></td>
  <td><a>World</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a>!</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to style the `a` element in every `td` to be 100 percent height:

```
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  height:400px;
}
a {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  display:block;
}
```

[This (JsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/rp60pe58/8/) works fine on IE and Chrome. However Firefox seems to have a problem with the colspan.

So I tried to change the given fixed height on `tr` instead of `td`:

```
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%
}
tr {
  height:400px;
}
a {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  display:block;
}
```

[This (JsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/rp60pe58/9/) works fine on Firefox and Chrome, but not on IE.

On the right side is, what I want:

[image: Grid]

How can I make this work in all Browsers?

Answer (score 0):

if you want more control over the TDs, i would highly suggest to use the display option of table and table-cell:

```
.table-wrapper{
  position:relative;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.table-wrapper a{
  position:relative;
  display:table-cell;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

you can easily choose the width, and control the content of "table-cell". This is supported by IE9.

link of demo:https://jsfiddle.net/keinchy/mq3nafje/6/